# Wait for reactive change stream subscription to be active with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

When subscribing to [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) using the [blocking Spring Data Mongo implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#change-streams) one can call [await](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/messaging/Subscription.html#await-java.time.Duration-) to wait for a subscription to become active:

```
Subscription subscription = startBlockingMongoChangeStream();
subscription.await(Duration.of(2, SECONDS));
Document someDocument = ..
writeDocumentToMongoDb(someDocument);
```

The `startBlockingMongoChangeStream` is implemented along these lines:

```
public Subscription startBlockingMongoChangeStream() {

    MessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer(template);
    container.start();                                                                                        

    MessageListener<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>, Document> listener = System.out::println;                     
    ChangeStreamRequestOptions options = new ChangeStreamRequestOptions("user", ChangeStreamOptions.empty()); 

    return container.register(new ChangeStreamRequest<>(listener, options), Document.class);
}
```

If `await` is not used in the example above there's a chance (virtually 100% chance if the JVM is hot) that `someDocument` is written *before* the subscription is active and thus the `someDocument` is missed. So adding `await` mitigates this issue.

I'm looking for a way to achieve the same thing when using the reactive implementation. The code now looks something like this:

```
Disposable disposable = startReactiveMongoChangeStream().subscribe(); // (1)
Document someDocument = ..
writeDocumentToMongoDb(someDocument).subscribe(); // (2)
```

The problem here is, again, that `someDocument` is written before the subscription returned by `startReactiveMongoChangeStream` has started and thus the document is missed.

Also note that this is a somewhat contrived example since in my actually application `writeDocumentToMongoDb` (2) is not aware of the `startReactiveMongoChangeStream` subscription (1) so I cannot simply `flatMap` (1) and call (2). The `startReactiveMongoChangeStream` method is implemented along these lines:

```
public Flux<ChangeStreamEvent<String>> startReactiveMongoChangeStream() {
    return reactiveTemplate.changeStream(String.class) 
                           .watchCollection("user")
                           .listen();    
}
```

How can I "simulate" the `await` functionality available in the blocking implementation in the reactive implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

There are no means for synchronization in the reactive API

### Explanation

First, let's look at both implementations to understand why this is.

The blocking implementation uses MongoDB's cursor API to obtain a cursor. Obtaining a cursor includes a conversation with the server. After `MessageListenerContainer` has obtained the cursors, it switches the subscription task to active which means that you have awaited the stage where the first cursor was fetched.

The reactive implementation operates on a `ChangeStreamPublisher`. From the reactive streams protocol, one can get notified when an element is emitted, when the stream completes or fails. There's no notification available when the server-side activity starts or completes. Therefore, you cannot wait until the reactive API receives the first cursor. Since cursors may be empty, the first cursor might not emit any value at all.

I think the MongoDB driver *could* provide a callback-style API to get notified that the stream is active. That's however something to report in the [MongoDB issue tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/).